# How to do this in programmatic way

Tags: vuejs2

I am doing below code in a vue.js application. I would like to do this in a programmatic way to reduce the code size.

```
display_input(valu) {
            if(valu == 'editName') {
                this.editName = true
                this.editAddress = false
                this.editTelephone = false
                this.editEmail = false
            }
            if(valu == 'editAddress') {
                this.editName = false
                this.editAddress = true
                this.editTelephone = false
                this.editEmail = false
            }
            if(valu == 'editTelephone') {
                this.editName = false
                this.editAddress = false
                this.editTelephone = true
                this.editEmail = false
            }
            if(valu == 'editEmail') {
                this.editName = false
                this.editAddress = false
                this.editTelephone = false
                this.editEmail = true
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following, it can all be compressed into:

```
display_input(valu) {
    this.editName = valu == 'editName'
    this.editAddress = valu == 'editAddress'
    this.editTelephone = valu == 'editTelephone'
    this.editEmail = valu == 'editEmail'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest way that I could thought, with the bonus that if you add any attribute you won't need to change it.

```
display_input(valu) {
    Object.keys(this).forEach(key => {
        this[valu] = valu == key
    })
}
```